# LEFT JOIN com HAVING

Tags: sql-server, join

Caso eu tenha que usar um agrupamento que envolva um campo da minha tabela que esteja relacionada através do LEFT JOIN e precise utilizar o HAVING, como ficaria ?
Sei que no WHERE não posso colocar pois ignora o LEFT e se torna obrigatório o valor.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Caso não queira que o campo do `LEFT` seja obrigatório você pode verificar se ele não é `NULL` primeiro:

```
...
WHERE (chave_tabela_left IS NULL OR campo_tabela_left = 'VALOR DESEJADO')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde!!
Tenta passar a condição dentro das condições de ligação, tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 t1
  LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2
    ON t1.chave = t2.chave AND t2.chave <> 2
```

Espero que dê certo!